# row_number() over partition by resource consumption

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If the table contains lots of different partition by id (10K+) and the size of the table is growing (with millions of records), will it run into out of memory issue?
When this query runs, does system require to store partition window (which would be 10K then) in to memory as well as `row_number` for each partition?

Comment: Sure, it's safe. Will things get slower? Sure... how slow? Depends on your environment. I'm an advocate for only changing things when there is a need... not prematurely optimizing. I'm not sure what you mean by row_number index, but maybe you mean indexed view?

Comment: You are not really using terms that mean anything. What does "safe" mean? What does "store in the memory in order to be tracked" mean? Store what in memory? What do you mean by tracked?

Comment: What does a "ROW_NUMBER index" mean to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to use it. How it will perform - it depends. If there is a "POC index" (Partition, Order by, Cover), i.e. an index with your partition by column as a first key column, then your order by column(s) as key column(s), and the selected columns as included columns, it will be the best for this particular query. But you should consider the pros and cons of this index. If there is no such index (or similar), the query will be heavier - think for table scan, spills to tempdb, etc. What will be the impact on your server - you should test to see.